# How to indicate in a text area there are more lines of text hidden?

Tags: textbox

We are talking about a dialog in a Windows desktop application.

I have text areas that most of the time contain only one line of text, but may occasionally contain several lines. Due to limited space it would be great to display the text areas only one line height and if there's more text then somehow indicate the area should be expanded. (the user can expand the area with a simple resize grabber in the corner)

How to indicate that?
I made 3 options:
[image]

If the ... buttons are clicked the area would grow to show the full content. But which one tells the user that? Do you have any other idea?

Thanks!

Comment: are these 3 lines separate complete sentences, as opposed to long overflow text?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about adding a little extra vertical space to your page/form to fit proper text areas. Users don't mind scrolling: http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll

Comment: Is the text editable? Or are you using this control to display read-only text?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  
- It can be either 3 separate sentences or 1 long sentence wrapped. That's why simply putting ... at the end of the text is not good as the first line can be only 1 word.  
- This is a dialog in a Windows desktop software, not a webpage, so scrolling is the last resort.
- Yes, text is editable.

Answer (score 5):

**The default textarea control already handles this.**

> When overflow occurs in a textarea control scrollbars appear above the
> resize handle. However, If you had a single line textarea these scrollbars
> wouldn't be viable.
>
> [image: Blockquote]

As far as UX goes you should always show at least 2-3 lines of a textarea to differentiate it from a standard input box (which doesn't allow <kbd>Enter</kbd>/Line breaks).

I would also recommend auto-sizing it bigger on focus if there is any truncated text.

Textarea resize codepen: https://codepen.io/FritzAPI/pen/mwVdow

Comment: I'll see if I can fit in 2 lines of text and I also like this "auto-sizing it bigger on focus" idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Use a gradient overlay and text prompt**

This borrows from the now-common 'Continue Reading' buttons seen on news sites and blogs.

In this case, instead of a button, you have a simple text prompt that draws attention to the expand button.

[image]